# Capacitors from ground to +12V and -12V. What is the purpose?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

I am working on converting a circuit design and encountered a series of capacitors between the +12V and -12V rails with ground in between. There are no components that use +12V or -12V in the schematic. There are no other connections to this other than the common ground connection. All the components of the circuit are powered by a separate +5v rail that is provided (and has appropriate decoupling capacitors.) Does this serve any purpose?

[image]

Comment: So what were the +12V and -12V were used for *before* your conversion?  No one puts decoupling capacitors on a board without a purpose.  I would not be so quick to exclude them.

Answer (score 1):

These are noise-suppression capacitors for the + and - 12 VDC buses. Even if there are no other connection to V<sub>DD</sub> or V<sub>SS</sub>, they might have been placed on *that* PCB for convenience.

However, check the schematic for other components carefully. Sometimes an IC pin is labeled V<sub>DD</sub>, ground or V<sub>SS</sub> *without showing the connecting trace*.

As for the reason for three separate caps, it's for differing frequency realms. The 10 μF electrolytic will bypass audio frequencies (e.g., 60 Hz hum), and smaller ceramic caps are used for RFI bypass (e.g., a few hundred kHz switching supply noise).

Answer (score 1):

Often, decoupling capacitors are collected together on the schematic, unrelated to specific components (e.g. chip supply pins).  This may be for organization (saves clutter near devices; but, one might indeed prefer seeing them near their respective parts -- it's a preference, not a rule*), or to facilitate layout.  (It is never to mean that the caps all glom together on the PCB!)

*I mean, it might be a rule at some companies.  But at others, the opposite might be the rule.  Most I think don't care either way, as long as it works.

Personally, I prefer grouping them together, as I can just add or remove some capacitors while I'm doing the layout.  The PCB layout informs how many capacitors the circuit needs, and I place them where needed.  Which in turn, works because capacitors can generally be shared between nearby devices.  Extras may also be needed, strewn around without respect to particular loads.  There are many variables involved in this process; as an expert engineer, I'm comfortable with this, but it's best to stick with pairing bypass caps and devices until you have the experience to do otherwise.

Further reading: power distribution networks (PDNs), RLC network theory, chip datasheets/appnotes, etc.

I recall Altera (now Intel) having an actually good appnote on this.  Most chips, they simply ask for caps nearby and that's it -- a risky proposition, actually, but it's right more often than it's wrong, so I don't mind it as a starting point.

---

I'm going to hazard a guess that your +/-12V system is analog, and even the above capacitor count may be overkill.  A pair of electrolytics is enough for most audio circuits, for example, but a few smaller (ceramic?) parts won't hurt, and a few more (strategically placed) is enough to run most any low-end microcontroller.